# Оставить цифры и символ «+» в начале

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Помогите, пожалуйста изменить регулярное выражение так, чтобы оставался символ «+» в самом начале и цифры.

```
$number = '+7 (123) 456 78+ 90+';

echo preg_replace('/[^\+\d]+/', '', $number);
```

Сейчас «+» остаётся везде и результат выглядит так: `+712345678+90+`, а необходимо так: `+71234567890`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте

```
$s = preg_replace('~^(\+)|\D+~', '$1', $s);
```

[Пример работы регулярного выражения](https://regex101.com/r/dhgaqW/1)

**Подробности**

- `^(\+)` - начало строки и знак `+`, захватываемый в подмаску №1
- `|` - или
- `\D+` - 1 и более символов, отличных от цифр.

Шаблон замены - `$1`, обратная ссылка на значение, хранящееся в подмаске №1.

Comment: Спасибо Вам, всё отлично работает! :)